# Override ASP.NET WebForms MasterPage Header Render Function for SEO

Tags: asp.net, webforms, master-pages

Our ASP.NET WebForms MasterPage is making a muck of our meta data and title. If you go to http://beta.orcsweb.com you will notice our meta tags don't have line breaks and the proper formatting, and the title tag has added in line-breaks. Even though we setup our MasterPage file with the proper formatting ASP.NET makes a big mess of it.

Anyone have any ideas or links on how to override how ASP.NET renders this so I can make it have just the formatting I expect.

(I know, move to ASP.NET MVC--that is a future project and not an immediate option.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help, and it also removes excessive white space, line feeds, etc:

http://beta.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/PageTags.aspx

Note, you can set page title at the page level - from an SEO point of view, this is what you should be doing.